# Combine known-size slices into an array in rust

Tags: rust, benchmarking, microbenchmark

Trying to find the optimal way to combine slices into a database key.

I need a slice that contains three things (concatenated):

1. A prefix byte (u8)
2. A slice that is passed in of a compile-time known size (20 bytes)
3. A slice that is passed in of a compile-time known size (32 bytes)

I've tried benchmarking the following 3 functions.  I would have expected "slot_key_array" to be the fastest, since its not allocating a vector, but "slot_key_sized" is consistently the fastest.  Why?

```
#[inline]
pub fn slot_key_vec(address: &[u8], slot: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
  let mut key: Vec<u8> = vec![DB_PREFIX_SLOT];
  key.extend_from_slice(address);
  key.extend_from_slice(slot);
  key
}

#[inline]
pub fn slot_key_sized(address: &[u8], slot: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
  let mut key: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(1 + 20 + 32);
  key.push(DB_PREFIX_SLOT);
  key.extend_from_slice(address);
  key.extend_from_slice(slot);
  key
}

#[inline]
pub fn slot_key_array(address: &[u8], slot: &[u8]) -> [u8; 53] {
  let key: [u8; 53] = [
    DB_PREFIX_SLOT,
    address[0], address[1], address[2], address[3], address[4], address[5], address[6], address[7],
    address[8], address[9], address[10], address[11], address[12], address[13], address[14], address[15],
    address[16], address[17], address[18], address[19],
    slot[0], slot[1], slot[2], slot[3], slot[4], slot[5], slot[6], slot[7],
    slot[8], slot[9], slot[10], slot[11], slot[12], slot[13], slot[14], slot[15],
    slot[16], slot[17], slot[18], slot[19], slot[20], slot[21], slot[22], slot[23],
    slot[24], slot[25], slot[26], slot[27], slot[28], slot[29], slot[30], slot[31],
  ];
  key
}
```

Comment: How have you benchmarked? When benchmarking with `criterion`, I get the expected result.

Comment: However, if you make them arrays instead of slices, you get another big speedup (2.7x).

Comment: They're unfortunately coming from another library, which provides slices to the underlying data rather than arrays...   Results from criterion are below (very consistent numbers):
storage_interface_keys/slot_key_vec
                        time:   [26.863 ns 26.873 ns 26.884 ns]
storage_interface_keys/slot_key_sized
                        time:   [13.733 ns 13.781 ns 13.830 ns]
storage_interface_keys/slot_key_array
                        time:   [19.949 ns 19.964 ns 19.979 ns]

Comment: This is also specifically with black_box() around the inputs to each function.  Without black_box I get roughly the same results for vec/sized, but much faster for array.  I assume its something to do with inlining?  Possibly faster in actual usage since it would be inlined?

Comment: Interesting... If I set the target platform to more modern than the default (`-C target-cpu=native`), LLVM uses more modern vectorization instructions, but this is actually a pessimization here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably on Linux, where the default allocator is good (I benchmarked on Windows, by replacing the allocator to `mimalloc` I got the same results).

This is because the array versions need to do bounds checking for each element, which prevents vectorizing and adds overhead. But they don't have to: if we make the arguments arrays instead of slices, the bounds checking will be gone.

```rust
pub fn slot_key_array_arrays(address: &[u8; 20], slot: &[u8; 32]) -> [u8; 53] {
    // ...
}
```

If you only have slices, you can convert them to arrays with `try_into()`:

```rust
#[inline]
pub fn slot_key_copy_array_try_into(address: &[u8], slot: &[u8]) -> [u8; 53] {
    slot_key_array_arrays(address.try_into().unwrap(), slot.try_into().unwrap())
}
```

Another alternative is to use [`copy_from_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice):

```rust
#[inline]
pub fn slot_key_copy_from_slice(address: &[u8], slot: &[u8]) -> [u8; 53] {
    let mut key: [u8; 53] = [0; 53];
    key[0] = DB_PREFIX_SLOT;
    key[1..][..20].copy_from_slice(address);
    key[21..].copy_from_slice(slot);
    key
}
```

Benchmark:

```
copy_from_slice         time:   [6.8321 ns 6.8841 ns 6.9611 ns]
Found 13 outliers among 100 measurements (13.00%)
  4 (4.00%) high mild
  9 (9.00%) high severe

array_try_into          time:   [4.6906 ns 4.7001 ns 4.7119 ns]
Found 11 outliers among 100 measurements (11.00%)
  3 (3.00%) high mild
  8 (8.00%) high severe

array_arrays            time:   [4.8212 ns 4.8325 ns 4.8473 ns]
Found 15 outliers among 100 measurements (15.00%)
  4 (4.00%) high mild
  11 (11.00%) high severe

array                   time:   [12.963 ns 12.992 ns 13.029 ns]
Found 17 outliers among 100 measurements (17.00%)
  5 (5.00%) high mild
  12 (12.00%) high severe

sized                   time:   [10.116 ns 10.218 ns 10.327 ns]
Found 4 outliers among 100 measurements (4.00%)
  2 (2.00%) high mild
  2 (2.00%) high severe

vec                     time:   [25.602 ns 27.162 ns 29.211 ns]
Found 7 outliers among 100 measurements (7.00%)
  6 (6.00%) high mild
  1 (1.00%) high severe
```

So, your version with arrays instead of slice is the fastest together with `try_into()` (same performance), then `copy_from_slice()`, and then the others.

Yet another alternative is to help LLVM eliminate the bound checks. It has problems here because you index in increasing order: we check for index 0, but that means nothing about index 1, so we check it too, then 2, then 3... but if we check the last index first, LLVM knows that all previous indices also exist:

```rust
#[inline]
pub fn slot_key_array(address: &[u8], slot: &[u8]) -> [u8; 53] {
    address[19];
    slot[31];

    // ...
}
```

This brings this code on par with the arrays version:

```
array                   time:   [4.6107 ns 4.6164 ns 4.6238 ns]
                        change: [-65.325% -64.755% -64.411%] (p = 0.00 < 0.05)
                        Performance has improved.
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer!  I actually tried a few things to get rid of the bounds checking, specifically with `assert_eq!(address.len(), 20)` etc, but didn't end up improving the speed.  Apparently just had to read the value :)

Answer (score 0):

`slot_key_sized` is best for a simple reason it's allocate only once compared to `slot_key_vec` who probably at least allocate twice.

`slot_key_array` is slow cause you are doing multiple indexing get on the slice, if the compiler is not smart enough it will check several time the len of the slices.

A probably better version is:

```rust
#[inline]
pub fn slot_key_array(address: &[u8], slot: &[u8]) -> [u8; 53] {
  let mut key: [u8; 53] = [0; 53];
  key[0] = 42;
  key[1..address.len() + 1].copy_from_slice(address);
  key[address.len() + 1..].copy_from_slice(slot);
  key
```

Comment: Stack protection has exactly zero overhead, since it is done by guarding a page at the end of the stack, thus it only have access if you touch it (but in this case, you're segfaulting). It also has overhead in very big arrays, but only once at function entry, and it's not relevant here.

Comment: The proof is my answer: if you remove the bound checks (also allowing vectorization), the array version is way faster.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman there is a lot of different stack protection. And I said "I could argue"

Comment: There is exactly one stack protector used in common platforms, and another one for when the stack usage overflow the size of a page.

Comment: whatever I remove it, that not the point of my answer anyway